# Enable/Disable Mask Modifier depending on object visiblity

Tags: python, modifiers, drivers

I would like to know if it possible for mask modifier to be automatically displayed based on the visibility of some object.

Example: I have a character with some basic clothes. Body of the character and every piece of clothing is a separate object. Let's say when object *Gloves* is visible in viewport/render, I would like for mask modifier *Mask_gloves* on object *Body* to turn on/display.

Is it possible to set up this kind of control?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've done this for example to hide a lower part of a t-shirt when jeans are set to visible, so that the t_shirt doesn't sometimes "poke through" the jeans (i.e., t-shirt is "tucked Under jeans and belt").

[image]

One does this using a "driver" based on another objects visibility or render-ability.

Another idea is to use a driver in some vertices that are assigned a material,  for example part of a character mesh that annoyingly appears through Armature-parented clothes, where I might instead "Mix" in the clothing color to clothing-adjacent body vertices, when the clothing item is to be rendered.

In the following, the viewport behavior is a bit "sluggish" when updated the controlling objects visibility in that one might have to "jiggle the threshold to update.  But if I animate the controlling objects visibility, it works fine.

In my example:  [image],  I hover over Cube visibility and "Copy as new driver", then hover over Mask visibility and "Paste driver", then edit to invert the logic.  Here you see the driver for Mask visibility (on Sphere VG), based on control (Cube) object visibility:

[image]

and here is when the cube is animated to be invisible in frame 1:

[image]

and visible in frame 2:

[image]

If you find my answer useful, please mark it as a solution.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce this effect using the drivers. I created drivers in same way as you described, however mask on object is not turning on/off when I change visibility of other object. I did some research on the internet and found some related discussion, it seems like this is a common "problem". Anyway you definitely pointed me in good direction, I will try to do some more research and maybe I will be able to find something.

Comment: @FMax -- yes you first have to get Mask modifier working *without* the driver.  perhaps assign the vertices in a VG with a weight less than 1.0.  Then as you slide "Theshold" up/down you should see the masking effect.  click on the left-right arrow next to the vertex group you're using to invert the vertices (from in-group to not-in-group).   [tutorial](https://youtu.be/wS-36yegLcg)

Comment: @FMax -- as I re-read your comment I think you refer to what I mention in my solution... You'll find that if you re-load your file, or jigger the Threshold around, it will pick up on enforcing the driver.  So there is def a bug here that I will report.   If I *animate* the visibility, it works perfectly to the frame's settings.

Comment: @FMax -- you are correct, as I just tried in on Subdivision modifier also.  I reported it as a [bug](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/106327) that you can subscribe/follow.